# The following lisp program doesn't work as expected

Tags: web, lisp

The followwing is my lisp code to complish a simple web server.

```
; 一些辅助函数
(require :asdf)
(defun loadlib (mod)
  (asdf:oos 'asdf:load-op mod))

(defun reload ()
  (load "web.lisp"))

; load 需要的库  
(loadlib :html-template)
(loadlib :hunchentoot)

; 设置 hunchentoot 编码
(defvar *utf-8* (flex:make-external-format :utf-8 :eol-style :lf))
(setq hunchentoot:*hunchentoot-default-external-format* *utf-8*)
; 设置url handler 转发表
(push (hunchentoot:create-prefix-dispatcher "/hello" 'hello) hunchentoot:*dispatch-table*)

; 页面控制器函数
(defun hello ()
  (setf (hunchentoot:content-type*) "text/html; charset=utf-8")
  (with-output-to-string (stream)
    (html-template:fill-and-print-template
     #P"/home/chonglinsun/Learn/cl/lib/web/index.tmpl"
     (list :name "Lisp程序员")
     :stream stream)))
; 启动服务器
(defun start-web (&optional (port 4444))
  (hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:acceptor :port port)))

(defun restart-web ()
  (progn
    (reload)
    (start-web)))
```

index.tmpl 的内容如下：

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test Lisp Web</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Lisp web开发实例</h1>
    hi, <!-- TMPL_VAR name -->
  </body>
</html>
```

When I start-web, I can not access localhost:4444/hello, but I can not firgure where 
the problem is. I searched the Internet, some people said that is my because of the 
path. But I do not think there is something related to it in my code. Hope there would be
someone coming tell me why. I used ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Are you trying to access the web server from another machine? If so, check your firewall settings.

Comment: No, I just use local machine to access it, where goes wrong ....

Comment: Are there compilation errors or warnings?  Hunchentoot can write logs, too---what do you find there?

Comment: There are no compilation errors or warnings, And the script didn't exit. When I access localhost:4444, the hunchentoot's log say that:127.0.0.1 - [2012-09-16 18:26:01] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 184 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0.1"

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an `easy-acceptor` instead of an `acceptor` to use the `*dispatch-table*` mechanism.